# Can i have more candidate keys than columns?

Tags: database, candidate-key

Is it possible to have more than n candidate keys in table of n columns? I know that i can have exactly n candidate keys f.e. in table where every piece of every record is different. But how about more candidate keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

You can have [compound keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_key). So if there are n simple keys then table can have **2^n - 1** superkeys.
But since candidate key is minimal superkey, there can be only **n** candidate keys.